# entity framework querying a sql view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to query a sql view in my project using Entity Framework and Linq.
I have been trying for hours now, but I just can't get it right.

```
var ii = context.view_DatabaseUsers.Any(usr => usr.DomainID == id);
```

Comment: What excatly does not work? Can you get more specific includig errors?

Comment: I seem to have found my problem, seems like I cnt update a sql view as its just a view from different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a view which only refers to one table in your database you can technically change your model.edmx to treat it as a table. After this you would be able to Create Update & Delete  with it. The downside is, that it will get overwritten, the next time you update your model, so you'd have to change it once again.

If the view is aggregating data from more than 1 table you'd have to stick to stored procedures, which you create on your database and map it via function mapping to your view in your model.

Comment: Its from multiple tables so store procedures it is.